# I want to validate EMAIL with Php's checkdnsrr()

Tags: php, html, dns

I have a Registration form, And want to check if the email is not fake.
I'm trying to use: `checkdnsrr($email)`.

But somehow it returns `FALSE` even if the email is right.

Comment: that is not so simple as you thought ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could try this Javascript code:

```
function isValidEmail($email){ 
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Or if you want to use PHP:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Comment: The question here is for Validating the email using checkdnsrr()

Answer (score 3):

[checkdnsrr](http://php.net/checkdnsrr) should be used to check the domain part only. So try this instead:

```
list($prefix, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
var_dump(checkdnsrr($domain, 'MX'));
```

Comment: *email is not fake* won't success .. you only check domain/MX Part, says nothing about a valid email-address account!

Comment: Perfect for checking if the domain has an MX record or not!